# Vertically centering an image in a grid template table cell

Tags: css, image, css-grid, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make a card where it consists of a header, image, content, and cta. On mobile view, I split the card into two columns: left with header, content, and cta, and right with the image.

```
grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
grid-template-areas: 
    "header image"
    "content image"
    "cta image";
```

And on regular view, the card is one column in the order header, image, content, and cta.

I am having trouble vertically aligning the image on the mobile view. It just remains at the top. On css-tricks, applying `align-self: center;` to .c-productCard__image seems to be the right choice to make it vertically align, but it did not move. I'm not really familiar with using grid template, so any advice would help.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/jennyydang/pen/bGVroJV?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on the image container `.c-productCard__image`

```
&__image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```